# React Native iOS: does uppercase vs lowercase matter for `fonts` folder and font filenames?

Tags: xcode, react-native, fonts, react-native-vector-icons, vector-icons

I'm adding `react-native-vector-icons` to my React Native project, and [these instructions](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios) tell me to drag the `Fonts` folder from `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons` to my project in XCode. All the font files in this `Fonts` folder start with capital letters. In this project, the existing `fonts` folder starts with lowercase, and the one font file in it already (`ionicons.ttf`) starts with lowercase.

**What I Want To Know:** Does it matter whether the `Fonts` folder or any of the font files in it start with uppercase or lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

The font file(eg: Nunito.tff) are required to be Case Sensitive.
You can click on the name of the font file and check for the **Exact** name.
In the Info.plist, copy and paste the exact name.

As to the question of the folder name, you can use any naming convention.
Just that, you need to run this command once you add the fonts folder in the root of your project

```
npx react-native link
```

That should add the necessary fonts to the app.